# oracle difference between two dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to find number of days between two dates.

Here's code:

```
declare
datum DATE;
sdate DATE;
shpord NUMBER;
rozdiel NUMBER;
MESSAGE VARCHAR(2000) := 'Nemozete Uvolnit VO c.';

begin
datum := TO_DATE('&OLD:NEED_DATE','DD.MM.YYYY');
sdate := TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY');

rozdiel := datum - sdate;
IF rozdiel > 5 THEN
   ERROR_SYS.Record_General('Nemozete Uvolnit VO c','');
END IF;
end;
```

I get an error:

> ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: @Consider in the future, please also edit out Thanks and other similar noise.  This will make your suggested edits more complete.

Comment: **Do not**: `sdate := TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY');`. `sysdate` is **already a date**. Your code takes `sysdate` and implicitly converts it into a string, because `to_date` takes a string. The format used for the implicit conversion is based on `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`. Then `to_date` translates that string back to a date. And if NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match the string you specify for back to a date, the round trip to string and back will either give an error or incorrect result.

Comment: Calling `to_date()` on a `date` value to convert it into a `date` is plain wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `to_date` on a date.  `sysdate` is already a `date`.  If you want to subtract midnight on the current day from `datum`

```
declare
  datum DATE;
  sdate DATE;
  shpord NUMBER;
  rozdiel NUMBER;
  MESSAGE VARCHAR(2000) := 'Nemozete Uvolnit VO c.';
begin
  datum := TO_DATE('&OLD:NEED_DATE','DD.MM.YYYY');
  sdate := trunc(sysdate);

  rozdiel := datum - sdate;
  IF rozdiel > 5 THEN
     ERROR_SYS.Record_General('Nemozete Uvolnit VO c','');
  END IF;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
sdate := TO_DATE('sysdate','DD.MM.YYYY');
```

to:

```
sdate := sysdate;
```

You're trying to convert the STRING 'sysdate' to a date, rather than the function result of sysdate.

also, watch your nls settings, if you date format isn't set to 'dd.mm.yyyy' you're going to get an error.

Comment: Hello, yes of corse, but with the same error. there is problem I think with different data types. but I don't know where.

Comment: ineed as ressult a NUMBER.

Comment: @denn: it works for me once I fix the 'sysdate' issue ... so if you're still getting an error, show the full script, show the full error ... so we can see what error / where it's occurring. (and show full input too :) )

Comment: This is the script: declare
datum DATE;
sdate DATE;
shpord NUMBER;
rozdiel NUMBER;
MESSAGE VARCHAR(2000) := 'Nemozete Uvolnit VO c.';

begin
datum := TO_DATE('&OLD:NEED_DATE','DD.MM.YYYY');
sdate := TO_DATE(sysdate,'DD.MM.YYYY');

rozdiel := ((datum) - (sdate));
IF rozdiel > 5 THEN
   ERROR_SYS.Record_General('Nemozete Uvolnit VO c','');
END IF;

end;

Comment: Perhaps the TO_DATE('&OLD:NEED_DATE','DD.MM.YYYY'); does not result in a correct input date after substitution?

Comment: @Tammert: could be, I actually changed that to `'&1'` for my test - not sure what that is .. :)

Comment: the error is: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: @denn: posting code in comments isn't very readable .. edit your original post please. And include the line # it mentioned in the error please.

Comment: @Shannon: True :) doesn't really hurt .. but just a waste ...Sometimes get focused on 1 thing, miss the obvious ;)

Comment: @Ditto, **Yes it does hurt, especially if `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` does not match the explicit format on `to_date`.**